# How to determine number of roots and what type for quartic equations?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quartics

I want to figure out the number of roots and their types in the quartic equation $$x^4-34x^2-x+272=0$$ without actually solving it. Is there such a way to do so?

Comment: I haven't learned calculus yet so I probably won't understand if you put a calculus related answer.

Comment: I dont know that rule

Comment: It is algebra, not calculus.

Comment: OK can u teach me how to do it then?

Comment: Let $f(x) =x^4-34 x^2-x+272$.  Try computing $f(x)$ for a few values of $x$?

Comment: I searched it up and it said to plug in x and -x into the equation and find the number of sign changes. I did that and i got 2 sign changes for when i plugged in x and 2 sign changes when i plugged in -x. Does that mean I have 2 positive roots and 2 negative roots?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It means that there are either zero or two positive roots and either zero or two negative roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this particular equation, you can let $f(x) = x^4 - 34x^2 - x + 272$ (this is just for convenience), and then calculate:

\begin{align*}
f(-5) &= 52 \\
f(-4) &= -12 \\
f(0) &= 27 \\
f(4) &= -20 \\
f(5) &= 42
\end{align*}

Since this function should look "continuous" when you draw it, and it changes sign between each of -5, -4, 0, 4, 5, this implies that there is a root in between any adjacent pair of each of these numbers, so we have at least two negative real roots and two positive real roots. I suspect that's what your sign changing business is supposed to mean.

Comment: Someone before stated that i should use descartes' rule of signs. That was what I was referring to. I think he/she deleted their comment. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4):

Descartes’ rule of signs tells us that there are either zero or two positive roots and either zero or two negative roots. That’s not much help. We can, however, examine the [Sturm chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem) for this polynomial for a more definitive answer.

With $P=x^4-34x^2-x+272$, we have $$ P_0 = P = x^4-34x^2-x+272 \\ 
P_1 = P' = 4x^3-68x-1 \\ 
P_2 = -\operatorname{rem}(P0,P1) = 17x^2+\frac34x-272 \\
P_3 = -\operatorname{rem}(P1,P2) = \frac{4615}{1156}x+\frac{65}{17} \\
P_4 = -\operatorname{rem}(P2,P3) = \frac{1296165}{5041}.
$$

There are four sign changes at $-\infty$: $(+,-,+,-,+)$ and zero at $+\infty$: $(+,+,+,+,+)$, therefore the number of real roots is equal to $4-0=4$. Combined with the results from the rule of signs, two of those roots are negative and two are positive.

Comment: My sincere compliments. I not know the Sturm chain for the polynomials.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't learned calculus yet so I don't understand how to do derivatives. Also, I don't know what negative rem is. Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what rem meant. But I did a bit of research and I still can't understand how to do Euclidean division. Can someone help?

Comment: @AidenChow Do you know how to divide one polynomial by another? It’s really the same process as the “long division” that you were taught in elementary school.

Comment: Oh that's the name for polynomial division. I never heard of it called that way. Thanks!

Comment: You could’ve simply looked up “Euclidean division of polynomials.” That takes you right to the “Polynomial long division” article in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Before delving into more general methods, it may be worth first checking whether the quartic is perhaps *reducible*. This can be done relatively cheaply e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082195/factorization-of-quartic-polynomial), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090587/strategy-on-factoring-quartic-polynomials-cross-method), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222702/quartic-as-a-product-of-quadratics), and it turns out that:

$$
x^4-34x^2-x+272 = (x^2 - x - 17) (x^2 + x - 16)
$$

Each quadratic factor has real roots, so the quartic has $\,4\,$ real roots.

Comment: Corrected a minor typo.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Thank you, that's better. I made another minor change to (hopefully) make it crystal clear now.