# How many roots are there of function $f(x)=x^4-3x^2+x-1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

**Problem:** How many (real) roots are there of function $f(x)=x^4-3x^2+x-1$

First, I can directly say since degree is $4$ then there can be at most $4$ roots of functions. Moreover, apparently $f(0)=-1$ and $\lim_ {x \to \pm \infty} = \infty$, so because of the **IVT** there are at least $2$ numbers $c,d \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(c)=f(d)=0$. One from negative and other one from positive side.

Actually, I can conclude the answer by sketching graph but which tool I can use to show that there are exactly $2$ roots for it without using graph.

Comment: could you elaborate what your question exactly is? also there are only two roots to f(x) as observed on graphing

Comment: @User0 OP probably means, how to prove that this has exactly 2 real roots

Comment: Basically you need to do a lot of inspecting and analysis in the intervals $(-2,-1),\ (-1,0),\ (0,1),\ (1,2).$

Comment: For any quartic function $f,$ the only possibilities are $0, 2, 4,$ if the coefficients are real. Now consider $f',$ which has either $1, 3$ zeros. Solve $f''=0$ to get $a, b.$ If $a, b$ are not real, then $f'$ has one zero, and so $f$ has either $0, 2$ zeros; it is easy to determine which by further considerations. Else, compute the sign of $f'(a)f'(b)=s.$ Then $f'$ has three distinct zeros provided $s\lt0.$ In this case, let the zeros of $f'$ be $p, q, r.$ Now compute the sign of $f(p)f(q)f(r)=S.$ Then $f$ has four zeros provided $S$ has the same sign as the leading coefficient of $f.$

Comment: A more straightforward approach might be to use Sturm's theorem as exemplified in one answer to the question linked by @DietrichBurde above (though it does not account for multiplicities, but that is a small matter).

Comment: Alt. hint: let $x_k \big|_{k=1,2,3,4}$ be the four roots, then by Vieta's relations $\,\sum \frac{1}{x_k^2}$ $= \left(\sum \frac{1}{x_k}\right)^2 - 2 \cdot \left(\sum \frac{1}{x_jx_k}\right)\,$ $= 1^2 - 2 \cdot 3 \lt 0$ so the four roots cannot *all* be real. P.S. @DietrichBurde FWIW this shortcut does not work for the quartic in the linked duplicate, so that's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @DavidP No, a quartic cannot possibly have *exactly* three zeros. I think the word you want is *distinct.* In that case I wonder where I claimed otherwise. In any case, my analysis covers all cases, as you would see if you didn't assume that whenever I said anything about zeros (except otherwise stated), I wasn't counting them with multiplicity.

Comment: For the link (someone has deleted the comment) see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513840/how-to-determine-number-of-roots-and-what-type-for-quartic-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1). The answers there are helpful, e.g., one can use Sturm's theorem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Your comment got automatically removed when the question was closed as a duplicate. I later voted to reopen it, for the reason explained in my previous comment, but I did not realize that having a gold badge in *any* of the tags meant instant reopening. My intention was not to single-handedly reopen the question, just queue it up for review, but there seems to be no way to withdraw a reopen vote.

Answer (score 2):

(*Posted as a CW to avoid any appearance of impropriety, since I voted to reopen the question.*)

More general techniques for determining the nature of the roots of a quartic have been mentioned in other comments and answers here, as well as under the related question [How to determine number of roots and what type for quartic equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513840/how-to-determine-number-of-roots-and-what-type-for-quartic-equations)

However, the particular quartic in the question here also allows for a "shortcut" solution.

- The OP covered half the way by noting that two of the roots must be real.

> apparently $f(0)=-1$ and $\lim_ {x \to \pm \infty} = \infty$, so because of the **IVT** there are at least $2$ numbers $c,d \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(c)=f(d)=0$. One from negative and other one from positive side.

- Let $\,x_i \big|_{i=1,2,3,4}\,$ be the four roots, then $\,\frac{1}{x_i}\,$ are the roots of the [reciprocal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial), or its opposite $\,-x^4 f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ $= x^4 - x^3 + 3 x^2 - 1\,$. By [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas): $$\,\sum_{1 \le i \le 4} \frac{1}{x_i^2} = \left(\sum_{1 \le i \le 4} \frac{1}{x_i}\right)^2 −2 \cdot \left(\sum_{1 \le i \lt j \le 4} \frac{1}{x_ix_j}\right) = 1^2−2⋅3 \lt 0$$
  It follows that the four roots cannot all be real, therefore the remaining two roots must be non-real complex conjugates.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need any calculus...

$P(x): f(x)=x^4-3x^2+x-1 = (x^2-2)^2+(x+0.5)^2-5.25.$

$Q(x): f(x)=x^2(x^2-3)+x-1.$

---

$\text{Case 1. } x \geq \sqrt{2}.$

$P(x) \Rightarrow f(x): \text{increasing function, } f(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}-3<0, \displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty}f(n) = \infty > 0.$

$\Rightarrow \text{There exists 1 real root for $f(x)=0$ in $[\sqrt{2}, \infty]$.}$

---

$\text{Case 2. } x \leq -\sqrt{2}.$

$P(x) \Rightarrow f(x): \text{decreasing function, } f(-\sqrt{2}) = -\sqrt{2}-3<0, \displaystyle \lim_{n \to -\infty} f(n)=\infty>0.$

$\Rightarrow \text{There exists 1 real root for $f(x)=0$ in $[-\infty, -\sqrt{2}].$}$

---

$\text{Case 3. } -\sqrt{2} < x < 1.$

$0 \leq x^2 < 2.$

$\Rightarrow -2.25 \leq x^2(x^2-3) \leq 0.$

$-\sqrt{2}<x<1.$

$\Rightarrow -\sqrt{2}-1<x-1<0.$

$\therefore Q(x) \Rightarrow f(x)<0, \text{No real root.}$

---

$\text{Case 4. } 1 \leq x < \sqrt{2}.$

$1 \leq x^2 < 2.$

$\Rightarrow 0<(x^2-2)^2 \leq 1.$

$1.5 \leq x + 0.5 < \sqrt{2}+0.5 < 1.5 + 0.5 = 2.$

$\Rightarrow 2.25 \leq (x+0.5)^2 < 4.$

$\therefore P(x) \Rightarrow f(x)<-0.25, \text{No root.}$

---

$\therefore f(x)=0 \text{ has only 2 real roots, each in } [\sqrt{2}, \infty] \text{ and } [-\infty, -\sqrt{2}].$

Comment: p(x) has 2 real roots and 2 other complex roots. Please check your last statement.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in the comments, using the graph, that is maximum, minimum, derivative, etc., with IVT is of course a good canonical way to discuss the number of solutions.

In this case we can also proceed for example as follows, let consider

$$g(x)=f(x)+1=x^4-3x^2+x=x(x^3-3x+1)$$

which has exactly four roots, one trivial at $x=0$ and the three others in the intervals $(-\infty,-1)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,\infty)$. Indeed $h(x)=x^3-3x+1\implies h'(x)=3x^2-3=0\;\text{as}\; x=\pm 1$.

Now we are interested in the extreme value of $g(x)$ between the roots at $x=0$ and at $x\in (0,1)$, which is a local maximum, indeed consider the derivative

$$g'(x)=4x^3-6x+1 \implies g'\left(\frac16\right)>0,\;\;g'\left(\frac15\right)<0$$

with maximum value bounded by

$$g(x)=f(x)+1=x^4-3x^2+x\le \left(\frac15\right)^4-3\left(\frac16\right)^3+\frac15<1$$

therefore $f(x)=g(x)-1$ has exactly $2$ roots in the intervals $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Why is this answer down-voted - Must provide a good reason!!!